# prevent javascript execute click event if not ready

Tags: javascript, html, click, jquery

```
previous.click(function(){
  if ((parseInt($('.slider-box').css('margin-left'))) < 0) {
    $('.slider-box').animate({'margin-left':'+='+rubrikWidth});
  }
});
```

This code executes a slider to move right, if a button is clicked and the the margin-left is < 0.
But when you click fast and often, the if-clause calculates to slow and then it is possible to move the slider to far.
i want to prevent the button to be clicked too fast.
is there a way to do:
click -> execute event -> and after this execution, you can click again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `animate` callback. This should do it, assuming `.slider-box` only matches a single element:

```
previous.click(function(){
  var slider = $('.slider-box');
  if (!slider.data('busy') && (parseInt(slider.css('margin-left'))) < 0) {
    slider.data('busy', true).animate({'margin-left':'+='+rubrikWidth}, function() {
        slider.data('busy', false);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if an animation is running by checking:

`$('.slider-box').queue('fx').length`

and use `preventDefault` if the queue's length is more than zero